# Windows 8.1 disable by default for the Administrative Share / root of each volume (c$)

Tags: windows, network-shares, windows-8.1

OS: Windows 8.1 Pro Media Center - 64bits)
windows 8.1 disable by default for the share folder root of each volume (c$),

how to enable back?

I try to access from my Mac - smb://192.168.1.2/c$, it immediate prompt access denied " You do not have permission to access this server."

UPDATE:
I also test in Windows XP / 7 in the same network environment, it also not allow to connect.

Screenshot for:
Control Panel / Network and Internet / Network and Sharing Center / Advanced sharing settings
[image]

[image]

Regedit: ( I am suing 64bit OS)
[image: regedit]

in my Mac OSX

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Administrative shares have been disabled in Windows Vista and later versions of Windows [for security reasons](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951016).

According to [Microsoft Support Knowledge Base article 947232](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947232), you can do one of the following:

1. Create your own shares with the appropriate permissions (recommended);
2. Run the Microsoft Fix It to perform an automatic workaround; or
3. Add to the Registry subkey
   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`
   a DWORD (32-bit) Value `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` with the value of `1`.

([source](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/81643))

---

You should also verify the following settings in Control Panel / Network and Internet / Network and Sharing Center / Advanced sharing settings :

**Network Discovery** : On
**File and printer sharing** : On
**File sharing for devices that use 40- or 56-bit encryption** : Enable
**Password protected sharing** : Off

Comment: from what you said Adminstrative shares have been disabled in Vista and alter version. However, my personal experience in Windows 7, I still can able access it without any problem. In this case, I had google this solution b4, but it does not work. Have you personally try your solution? I tried it, but still can't.

Comment: Check also the other points in [this link](http://chall32.blogspot.fr/2010/02/how-to-enable-access-windows-7.html). Use on the Mac a user account that has permissions on the share **and** on the disk. You may need to give the Everyone account these permissions. Setting permissions on the entire system disk is troublesome, insecure and will not work on some special folders, so is really truly not advised. Instead of using the administrative share on the system disk, create your own shares on parts of the disk. Checking if the Mac can access these non-administrative shares before is a good test.